# Does the azure python sdk support the azure resource manager api?

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm new to azure, I see that a new api/abstraction has been released called Azure Resource Manger, which will [superceed](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-azurerm-versus-azuresm) older azure service management :

I was trying to spin up an instance using the [azure python sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python), but I see the sdk still using the older concepts (afinity groups, virtual networks, hosted services). There is no mention of resource groups. Are this supported? If not when will this be added to the sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, currently Python SDK doesn't provide packages for new Azure Resource Manager APIs while it provides [components](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/documentation/index.html), i.e. [ServiceManagement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management/), Storage, and ServiceBus. Please feel free to submit your ideas and feedback on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [azure-mgmt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-mgmt) collection of packages, which use the new Resource Manager APIs.